# Receive touch events following an ACTION_OUTSIDE

Tags: android, overlay

**Context**

I have an overlay window (`TYPE_SYSTEM_ALERT`) which is full screen.

The flag `FLAG_NOT_TOUCHABLE` is enabled so that underlying window gets the touch events.

The flag `FLAG_WATCH_OUTSIDE_TOUCH` is also enabled so that my overlay gets an `ACTION_OUTSIDE` event when a touch event happens.

**Goal**

If a touch event happens in a specific area of the screen, I would like my overlay to become 'touchable' and receive all following touch events (move, up,...).

**What I tried**

I tried to remove the `FLAG_NOT_TOUCHABLE` when receiving the `ACTION_OUTSIDE` but I don't receive the touch events until the current series of touch is over (i.e `ACTION_UP` event).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well I finally ended up using 2 overlay windows:

- a `TYPE_SYSTEM_ALERT` with `wrap_content` to catch touch events on the content
- a `TYPE_SYSTEM_OVERLAY` with `match_parent`

And I transfer my content view from one window to another when touch starts/ends.

Comment: can u provide sample how u did this ?? i too facing same problem.